# How to dynamically insert and run code in script tag in React

Tags: reactjs

Here is my React component:

```
import { foo } from './foo'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.initSpecialScriptTagSetup()
    }

    initSpecialScriptTagSetup() {
        const scriptElement = document.createElement('script')
        scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript'
        scriptElement.async = true
        scriptElement.src = somesource
        scriptElement.innerHTML = "foo(someargument)";

        // Insert the new map script element before the closing </body> tag
        const scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
        const lastScriptElement = scripts[scripts.length - 1]
        lastScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, lastScriptElement.nextSibling)
    }

    render() {
        return (<div id="placeholder"></div>)
    }
}
```

When the component mounts, I want to be able to dynamically insert and run a special function `foo` which will insert third-party library content into the placeholder div.  Currently, my component mounts and the `script` tag is inserted properly but `foo` is not being called. I tried calling the init in the constructor instead but that gave me errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't allow you to do that. The best thing you can do is to use the `eval()` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

that is if you want to execute a code from a string, but if you want to include some external script file, then you simply do what you already did.

1. Create script element
2. Set the source attribute
3. Append the script element somewhere to DOM